# .Net C# System.Management.ManagementObject SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR value getting null on RegistryValueChangeEvent event

Tags: c#, system.management

I am developing registry monitor for watching particular keys, i am having a problem with  `System.Management.ManagementObject` `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` value getting null on `RegistryValueChangeEvent` event. Please kindly help

Comment: Please show your code (or what you have tried) to clarify your question.

Comment: Hi Naeem, please see below code                                                        
   void valuechange_RegistryValueChanged(object sender, RegistryValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {                     
            lsbDisplay.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
            lsbDisplay.Items.Add(string.Format("RegistryValueChangeEvent detected changed by {0} ,
                            
                e.RegistryValueChangeData.SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR == null ? "N/A" : e.RegistryValueChangeData.SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR[0].ToString())
                ));
            }));
        }